# The background ended but i'm not on the main thread

Tags: java, android, kotlin

So here is the flow of the app

- Start a background thread and give it the **this** as listener
- doinbackground method do some work than it calls **Listener.finishfun**
  The problem is not here . The problem is that   when this methods is called i test the following code

  `Looper.getMainLooper()==looper.mylooper` it gaves `true`

Meaning  that im not on the main thread  . How is that possible.
Why did i test that : because i can not call any method that runs on the main thread only and i get errors like
**glid**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must call this method on the main thread
```

**progress view** also show throws a similar error

**any one can explain??**

Comment: Why do you expect it to run inside the main thread, if you invoke it from the background thread? At least if I understood you correctly. It would be helpful if you share some of your code.

Answer (score 2):

The callback is called from whatever thread that calls it, not from the thread that happened to instantiate it or was responsible for passing it to the background thread.

If you want to call your callback on the main thread, you need to post it to a main thread Handler. For example:

```
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
    myCallback(someReturnValue)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad i didn't call the callback from `onpost`
Method